# WP_User_Query counter not updating with pagination

Tags: pagination, wp-user-query

Below is the code that I found (thanks to The_Sumo) on [this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57427/how-to-display-pagination-links-for-wp-user-query) and the code works like a charm. I am trying to add an additional column to the table that displays the ordered list number of the users like:

> 1 John Doe jon@example.com
>
> 2 Jane Doe jane@example.com

One method I tried that kinda worked - i.e. I created a counter before the condition statement (`$counter = 0`).

Then right after the opening bracket of the foreach loop, I am incrementing the counter by 1 (`$counter = $counter + 1;`) and printing the value of `$counter` within the table.

The issue I am facing is - when I click next page, the counter value starts from 1 again instead of continuing from where it left of.

So lets say I want to display 5 items in each page, so page 1 should display 1 - 5 and on page 2 6-10 - instead page 2 shows 1-5 again. Just the numbers. Any idea how to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
$number = $counter + ( $current_page - 1 ) * $users_per_page;
```

with your increasing `$counter` variable in the loop.

Here we assume `$counter >= 0`, `$current_page >= 1` and `$users_per_page >= 1`.

We might combine it into:

```
$number = ++$counter + ( $current_page - 1 ) * $users_per_page;
```

with `$counter = 0` as initial condition.